# Add member to distribution list using Microsoft Graph

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to add (and eventually remove) a member to a group using Graph. I can do it if the group is an Office365 group, but the issue is that I need to add it on a distribution list.

I am doing a POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/my_group_id_here/members/$ref and passing the following body:

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/user_id_here"
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "f39af99e-2ee9-406e-b5e0-9ace5bfaf123",
            "date": "2018-08-13T17:35:38"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add a member to a distribution list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
Graph API now supports adding members to distribution lists as long as they are managed in cloud. See [Add Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

---

CRUD operations against Distribution Lists are not supported by Microsoft Graph. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

> Use this API to add a member to an **Office 365 Group**, a **security group**, or a **mail-enabled security group** through the members navigation property.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a work around for this? I am coding a custom made application for our company, and we need to be able to add a new user to a distribution list so that we don't go into the office365 admin each time and do it manually.

Comment: I believe you can use the this Exchange PowerShell cmdlet: [`Add-DistributionGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/Add-DistributionGroupMember?view=exchange-ps).

Comment: Graph API now supports adding members to distribution lists. See [Add Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @Danstan If I try to do this via MS graph add-member / New-MgGroupMemberByRef 
 (beta) I still get the response "Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list." How were you able to add a member to a DL via MS Graph?

Comment: Yes, me too. Also interested how you were able to do this via the Graph API without getting that Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list error message?

Comment: To clarify, the Graph API now supports adding members to Unified Groups (or 365 Groups as they're commonly known). This doesn't include classic distribution groups.