# Add User to Multiple Distribution Lists in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need a working Graph API script for adding user to multiple distribution Lists in Office 365

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827823/add-member-to-distribution-list-using-microsoft-graph/51830465#51830465) and see if it can give you somewhere to start.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you can add users to groups including distribution list as long as they are managed through the cloud. See [Add member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

In your case, you can use [PowerShell SDK for Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0) - Specifically the [New-MgGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/new-mggroupmember?view=graph-powershell-1.0).

For example

```
New-MgGroupMember  -GroupId "dl-group-id" -DirectoryObjectId "user-id"
```